# Move image inside a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a div with a specific width and height. And a smaller image with the same width but much less height. How could I

> - Position the small image to the inside top of the big div (but still all the small image to be visible in it)
> - Animate the small image from the inside top of the big div to the inside bottom (and again, still keep it all visible)
> - Inverse the process to go to the top again

I 've been totally confused with this one. All widths/heights are known, so they don't need to be calculated dynamically.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want the image to animate down then up immediately? Or do you want control over the up/down movement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see an example of the code [here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/KgWK4/)

In general look at the [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method of jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

1. Set position:relative on the containing div.
2. Set position:absolute on the image.
3. Use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) to increment the **top** CSS property of the image until it equals (containing div's height) - (image's height)
4. Once that is reached, do the same except decrement the **top** property until 0
5. goto 3 :)